# How could i use result from a rule as input in another rule

Tags: java, drools

I want to make rule decision based on a result from another rule.

My decision table:
[decision table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Jhc.jpg)

Comment: i have tried to use priority(saliance) to make last two rules execute after rules above..

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuilt function of drools 'update'.
It tells the engine that an existing object in the working memory has changed.
'

Comment: i am using update() in action column as you can see in screenshot i provided..when i set output attribute i update my object.. and with a saliance i made rules fire in order i want.. but nothing happens